# Updating column data based on row condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to update a dataframe with 153 rows and 291 columns with the first column being a product description and all other columns numeric.

Most of the rows sum to 1, but due to some bad data input, some have had their values doubled.

I want to update columns based upon if the rowsum is larger than 1. So that the row sum becomes 1.

A small example data:

```
test <- data.frame(product = c("First", "Second", "Third"),
                   a = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.2),
                   b = c(0.4, 0.1, 0.2),
                   c = c(0.4, 0.8, 1.6)
                   )
  product   a   b   c
1   First 0.2 0.4 0.4
2  Second 0.1 0.1 0.8
3   Third 0.2 0.2 1.6
```

I've tried using

```
test %>% mutate(across(2:ncol(test), if_else(rowSums(.) > 1, . / 2, .)))
```

but get the following error:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(2:ncol(test), if_else(rowSums(.) > 1, ./2, .))`.
x 'x' must be numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to ensure that each row sum is no more than 1:

```r
library(tidyverse)

test <- data.frame(
  product = c("First", "Second", "Third"),
  a = c(0.2, 0.1, 0.2),
  b = c(0.4, 0.1, 0.2),
  c = c(0.4, 0.8, 1.6)
)
test
#>   product   a   b   c
#> 1   First 0.2 0.4 0.4
#> 2  Second 0.1 0.1 0.8
#> 3   Third 0.2 0.2 1.6

test_long <-
  test %>%
  pivot_longer(-product) %>%
  group_by(product)
test_long
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   product [3]
#>   product name  value
#>   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 First   a       0.2
#> 2 First   b       0.4
#> 3 First   c       0.4
#> 4 Second  a       0.1
#> 5 Second  b       0.1
#> 6 Second  c       0.8
#> 7 Third   a       0.2
#> 8 Third   b       0.2
#> 9 Third   c       1.6

scaled_test <-
  test_long %>%
  filter(sum(value) > 1) %>%
  mutate(value = value / sum(value))
scaled_test
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   product [1]
#>   product name  value
#>   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 Third   a       0.1
#> 2 Third   b       0.1
#> 3 Third   c       0.8

test_long %>%
  filter(sum(value) <= 1) %>%
  bind_rows(scaled_test) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   product [3]
#>   product     a     b     c
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 First     0.2   0.4   0.4
#> 2 Second    0.1   0.1   0.8
#> 3 Third     0.1   0.1   0.8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: But now all the rows are the same? I wanted to basically only divide each column value of the third row with 2 so that the sum of the row was equal to 1. Similar to the other rows.

Comment: Do you just wanna normalize the data so that the sum of each row having a row sum larger than 1 to 1 and nothing else?

Comment: I principle yes. Just in this case, it was all doubled values. But a more general approach would be fine as well.

Comment: @Godrim I revised my answer

Answer (score 1):

In `base`, you can solve it this way:

```
idx <- rowSums(test[, -1]) > 1

test[idx, -1] <- test[idx, -1] / 2

test

#  product   a   b   c
#1   First 0.2 0.4 0.4
#2  Second 0.1 0.1 0.8
#3   Third 0.1 0.1 0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `across` -

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  mutate(across(a:c, ~./ifelse(rowSums(select(cur_data(), a:c)) > 1, 2, 1)))

#  product   a   b   c
#1   First 0.2 0.4 0.4
#2  Second 0.1 0.1 0.8
#3   Third 0.1 0.1 0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, (names(test)[-1]) := .SD/(1 + (rowSums(.SD) > 1))[col(.SD)], .SDcols = a:c]
test
   product   a   b   c
1:   First 0.2 0.4 0.2
2:  Second 0.1 0.1 0.4
3:   Third 0.2 0.2 0.8
```